# How do I do a Regex path match for a POST request with Nock.js?

Tags: nock

I am trying to chain some requests in Nock with Regex matching on the path. All of the examples I see of Regex path matching are get requests. How do I do this properly? Is the below right?

```
nock('https://base-url.com')
            .post('/v1/secrets/*$', {
                username: 'pgte',
                email: 'pedro.teixeira@gmail.com',
            })
            .reply(200)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code demonstrates a successful Nock on a POST request using a regex on the path.

```
nock('https://base-url.com')
  .post(/^\/v1\/secrets\/.*$/, {
    username: 'pgte',
    email: 'pedro.teixeira@gmail.com',
  })
  .reply(200, 'OK')

const resp = await axios.post('https://base-url.com/v1/secrets/foobar', {
  username: 'pgte',
  email: 'pedro.teixeira@gmail.com',
})

expect(resp.status).toBe(200)
expect(resp.data).toBe('OK')
```

Things to note about the value passed to the `post` method; If you want to use regex matching, you need to pass an instance of a `RegExp` as the first argument. Here I'm using the short-hand notation, but you could also create an instance using the `new RegExp("...")` notation, if desired.

Also, the example in your question had the asterisk character directly after the last slash. Which translates to the path needs to end with zero or more slashes. I assume that's not what you want, but my point is, use something like https://regex101.com to validate your regexs.

Nock will test the `pathname` of the URL ([as defined here](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url-strings-and-url-objects)) against the regex, including the leading slash.